# Google Cloud Platform File Transfer Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Issue: Can't transfer files via FileZilla I get an error in the console saying "Permission Denied". I know why I am getting that error. I can't log in as a root user via SFTP because in the username field I have an ssh key that allows me to get into my Google Cloud Platform VM via FileZilla

Edit: What can I do to fix this issue or get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://onepagezen.com/fix-ftp-permission-errors-google-cloud/) for "Permission denied" issues when uploading files to your vm thru SFTP.

1. Identify Error
   Permission denied errors occur when you don’t have the required permissions to make changes to a file that you’re trying to edit over FTP.
2. Connect to VM Instance
   Connect to your VM instance using the SSH (Linux Shell) terminal.
3. Check File Permissions
   Execute the following command:

`stat -c "%a %n" /path/to/file`

4. Edit File Permissions
   Run the following command:

`sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file`